# GtkNotebook - как переключаться между виджетами?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk+, glade

Нужно сделать переключение между виджетами: нажимаю допустим кнопку корзина - открывается виджет корзины, нажимаю скриншоты - открывается виджет со скриншотами. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал просто запихнуть в GtkBox все виджеты и по нажатиям кнопкок показывать одни и скрывать другие, но это колхозно и неудобно когда этих виджетов будет много. Нашел какие-то контейнеры GtkNotebook и GtkStack, вроде они позволяют сделать интерфейс как у окна на 1-ом и 2-ом фото, запихнул GtkNotebook в проект, но как переключать виджеты я так и не понял
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для документации используйте программу `devhelp`.
вот пример как создать notebook.

```
GtkWidget *note = gtk_notebook_new ( );
/* виджет frame например и есть frame */
/* чтобы добавить в виджет frame другой виджет, надо использовать контейнер */
gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) frame, box );
/* то есть создаешь из боксов нужное расположение виджетов и потом добавляешь в frame */
/* потом этот frame добавляешь уже в notebook */
gtk_notebook_append_page ( ( GtkNotebook * ) note, frame, gtk_label_new ( "Page 1" ) );
```

тот что на снимке nautilus файловый менеджет, так там возможно виджет слева GtkPlacesSidebar. это всё в документации `devhelp` есть. можно открыть в документации widget gallery и посмотреть какие виджеты есть.
чтобы ваш уровень быстренько повысить до нормального, предлагаю посмотреть код моей программы [binance](https://github.com/xverizex/binance)

Comment: Программа очень интересная) Буду подсматривать в ваш код:)